# Delay between request/response

Tags: java, delay

The problem:
  I have 2 methods:

```
proccessRequest();
proccessResponse();
```

if I run them so then I get an error because the request proccessing take too long and the response part gives an error. But if I add Thread.sleep(300); between them, then it run fine.

```
proccessRequest();
Thread.sleep(300);
proccessResponse();
```

What would be a good solution for this? Stopping the app with Thread.sleep isnt a good solution.
Should I use some kind of timer?

Comment: What do the methods do? Are they asynchronous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for [locks](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html) and [conditions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html). Your response needs to wait for the request to complete. If they are threads, your response needs to ***Join*** the request.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using [locks](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/locks.html).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `processRequest()` doesn't actually wait for a response to be ready. When there is no delay in between, response is not yet there (because it takes much more time to produce it than spent in method calls). And `processResponse` quite reasonably handles this as a timeout.